# Which one is right outta the following?

Tags: word-choice

> Stack exchange is a question asking site
>
> Stack exchange is a question answering site

I guess both are wrong
.
Anyways i just wanted a word of that sort...

Btw stackexchange has always been best yeh ❣

Comment: "I guess both are wrong." Why do you say that?

Comment: outta is slang for: I wanna get outta here, for example. Not used in regular writing.

Answer (score 1):

**question asking** and **question answering** are both valid formations and they can be used to modify a noun.

Consider these made up examples:

> *American Harvest* is a **dirt farming** journal.
>
> *The British Angler* is a **fly fishing** journal.
>
> *Dangerous Cats* is a **lion taming** journal.